# Deploy a release on maven central

Tags: java, git, maven, repository, gnupg

I would like to publish my Java program on maven central.
Uploading from a SNAPSHOT also worked. But when I try to publish a release I always get the following error message.

```
Nexus Staging Rules Failure Report
[ERROR] ==================================
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Repository "xxxxx" failures
[ERROR]   Rule "signature-staging" failures
[ERROR]     * No public key: Key with id: (xxxxx) was not able to be located on http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371. Upload your public key and try the operation again.
```

Then i tried to upload my key to the server with the following comand.

```
gpg --keyserver http://keyserver.ubuntu.com --send-keys xxxxx
```

Then i got this error.

```
gpg: WARNING: nothing exported
gpg: skipped "xxxxx": Not found
gpg: keyserver send failed: Not found
```

Does anyone have an idea what it could be?

Comment: There is a specific process that you need to follow, as described here: https://maven.apache.org/repository/guide-central-repository-upload.html. Idk what you're doing, because you haven't included nearly enough detail, but it doesn't seem to be following that process. You say "*Uploading ... a SNAPSHOT ... worked*" but Maven central doesn't support snapshots so...

Comment: When you run gpg --send-keys make sure you providing the full 40 characters, not just the 16 character ID that Nexus shows in the error report. You can also export the public key and paste it into the UI on the keyserver (just go to the keyserver URL in a browser). Export the key like:

gpg --armor --export ADB57376B4B9EEC269BE39FB738180XXXXXXXXXX > pubkey.asc

I've had similar problems getting a new key loaded, even though I followed the steps to the letter.

Comment: I have exported my public key and uploaded it to the keyserver, still not working.
[![xhDZ6.png](https://picr.eu/images/2020/09/10/xhDZ6.png)](https://picr.eu/i/xhDZ6)

Comment: What exactly does not work? Have you read this: https://central.sonatype.org/pages/requirements.html. checked all things working?